# Fetch doc.id in response along with data from a collection

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Fetching data from collection `leads` and showing all documents on Html table. On click, I need to fetch the doc.id of clicked item as it is the only **primary key**.

**P.S** I am getting records of all documents in array. I need the document id too in this same array.

Below is the code I am using to fetch the data. I am pushing in `tableData` array. I want docid **in this array.**

```
 this.firestore.collection('leads' , ref => ref 
.limit(5)
).snapshotChanges()
.subscribe(response => {
if(!response.length){
  console.log("no data available");
  return false;
}
this.firstInResponse = response[0].payload.doc;
this.lastInResponse = response[response.length - 1].payload.doc;


this.tableData = [];
for(let item of response){
  this.tableData.push(item.payload.doc.data()); 
  console.log(this.tableData);
}

...
```

Attaching screenshots of console.log and Firestore for clarity.

[image]

### Edit 1

After trying this

```
for(let item of response){
  var data = item;
  Object.assign(data, {id : item.payload.doc.id})
  this.tableData.push(data);
  console.log(this.tableData);
```

My actual array broke, below is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for(let item of response){
 var data = Object.assign(item.payload.doc.data(), {id : item.payload.doc.id})
 this.tableData.push(data);
 console.log(this.tableData);
}
```

I got the id from `item.payload.doc.id` and then added id property to the data Object and then pushed the modified object to tableData

Hope this helps!!

Comment: got the doc id, but this broke the actual array, i have updated the question see   `Edit 1`

Comment: this worked `  var data = Object.assign(item.payload.doc.data(), {id : item.payload.doc.id})
  this.tableData.push(data);`   you can update the answer,i'll accept it..thanks